# Sequences and Number Theory

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have a sequence defined as follows: $b_{n} = b_{n - 2} + b_{n-3}$ with $b_{0} = 3, b_{1} = 0$, and $b_{2} = 2$. My goal is to show that $b_{p}$ is divisible by p for any prime p. Here is my idea: Find the roots of $x^3 - x - 1$  and then use the three initial conditions to find an explicit formula. My problem: Well the roots are irrational(cube roots with square roots inside), so I have no idea how the claim follows. Is there any way I can improve my plan of attack, or is there a better way?

Comment: Finding the explicit form of the sequence probably isn't the way to go necessarily. Recall that the Fibonacci sequence would have terms dependent on powers of $(1 \pm \sqrt 5)/2$ even though the sequence is integers for instance: this sort of thing is not uncommon with recurrence relations. Clearly it'd be hard to conclude any divisibility property (yes, the Fibonacci sequence has some) from that alone. So you'll have to find a new angle of attack, probably -- what that is, however, I'm not sure...

Comment: Two proofs can be found [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/PerrinSequence.shtml)

Comment: I replaced the tag [tag:number-theory] by [tag:elementary-number-theory]. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: @lulu How do you show that in \begin{align}\displaystyle
(r_{1}+r_{2}+r_{3})^{p} &= \sum_{a+b+c=p-1}\frac{p!}{a!b!c!}r_{1}^{a}r_{2}^{b}r_{3}^{c}+(r^{p}_{1}+r^{p}_{2}+r^{p}_{3})\\
&= pz+(r^{p}_{1}+r^{p}_{2}+r^{p}_{3}),
\end{align} \begin{align}\sum_{a+b+c=p-1}\frac{p!}{a!b!c!}r_{1}^{a}r_{2}^{b}r_{3}^{c}\end{align} is an integer?

Comment: The sum should be over $a+b+c=p$ excluding cases in which two of the terms are $0$.  Then remark that the sum is a symmetric function  in the roots $r_i$ with integer coefficients, hence an integer.

Comment: I see that when the sum is a symmetric function with "variables" $r_{i}$, it is an element of $\mathbb{Z}[r_{1}, r_{2}, r_{3}]$. But how does that show that the sum is an integer? Can you please clarify?